# What is the probability that these passengers will exceed the weight capacity?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The weight of men in the United States is normally distributed with mean $E(X) = 185 $ pounds and standard deviation, $\sigma = 10$. If a boat containing $n=25$ total passengers of U.S. men has a weight capacity of 6,000 pounds. what is the probability that these passengers will exceed the weight capacity?

I am not really sure how to go about this problem. I'm guessing that you have to convert it into a z-score somehow, but I'm not sure how to apply the 25 men sample. I know that $Z = x-\frac{185}{10}$  or maybe $Z = x-\frac{185\sqrt{25}}{10}$. So what would I chose as my $X$? Would I divide 6000 by 25 to find the average weight it has to be to exceed the capacity? Just trying a few things, I got the probability that they will exceed the weight capacity to be basically zero. Not sure if that is correct, and could use some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the answer is very nearly 0, but (even after @Drew's nice edit) it does not
seem you are at all clear on how to get the answer.

Here is an outline:

1) The total weight $T = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{25}$ is normally
distributed. Figure out its mean $\mu_T$ and its SD $\sigma_T.$

2) Standardize: $P(T > 6000) = 
P\left(Z = \frac{T-\mu_T}{\sigma_T} > \frac{6000 - \mu_T}{\sigma_T}\right).$

3) Evaluate the quantity $\frac{6000 - \mu_T}{\sigma_T}$, and then the probability, using standard normal tables or software.

Below is a graph of the density function of the distribution of $T$,
Your answer is the area beneath the curve to the *right* of the
vertical red line.

[image]

Comment: To find the mean of the total weight, would you just divide 6000 by 25? And to find the standard deviation of the total weight, would it just be 10 * 25? @BruceET

Comment: Use $\mu_T = E(T) = E(X_1 + \cdots + X_{25}) = \sum_{i-1}^{25} E(X_i) = 25(185).$ And, because of independence, similarly for _variances_. Then take square root. Such formulas must be in your text. I suspect the purpose of this problem is to give you practice using them.

Comment: So for the variance I got 10890000, and the std dev I got 3300. I believe that'd be correct, right? @BruceET

Comment: No. $\sigma_T^2 = V(T) = \dots = 25(100),$ etc. Got an appointment. Will check back later.

Comment: Okay, doing this I got P(Z>27.5)=0 (approximately)... seems like a weird answer, idk. @BruceET

Comment: Btw, thanks for your help... very in depth answer. It really helped me understand.

Comment: By the Central Limit Theorem, the answer is $\approx 0$ even if weights have $\mu = 185$ and $\sigma = 10$ but are not exactly normally distributed. // You can also work this as $P(\bar X > 240)$ and use $\bar X \sim Norm(185, 2),$ where $E(\bar X) = \mu_X = 185$ and $SD(\bar X) = \sigma_X/\sqrt{n} = 10/\sqrt{25} = 2.$